# How long can I keep cannoli shells with no filling and how should I store them

Tags: storage-method

How long can I store cannoli shells with no filling?  What is the best way to do this?  I am traveling 5 days to my destination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: @ElmerCat : if it's a duplicate, which category does it go in?  (personally, I'd be worried about how to pack them so they won't crack in transit.)

Comment: @ElmerCat Along with what Joe said, "how do I store them" definitely isn't a duplicate, either.

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming you mean just the shells unfilled. If you made the shells yourself, line a cardboard box with paper bag material (cut up some) then just lay them in. They’ll be fine for a couple of weeks, probably longer. If you bought them, don’t worry about it they last just as long if not longer.  Just leave them in their original container.

Answer (score -1):

I found Saran wrapped individually helps.

Comment: We'd love to read more - for how long can you store them, what should be kept in mind when wrapping... Welcome to Seasoned Advice!